# Can I work civilian aircraft with just an FAA Airframe certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, military, avionics, airframe, airframe-and-powerplant

I am currently in the Air force, but plan on separating after my contract ends. I really like the field of avionics and aviation in general.(I am a B-1 Offensive Avionics Systems guy) However, when I went to my local FSDO, he told me I was not elegible to pursue the Powerplant portion of the A&P certification. I decided the Airframe was better then nothing, but am concerned about future employment requiring the full A&P licensure. I am a hard worker and would definitely, given the opportunity, use my time wisely to get the OJT needed to be eligible for the Powerplant part. Are there jobs in this field for someone with just the Airframe certificate?

Comment: _Why_ are you not eligible to pursue the P portion of an A&P? I'm pretty sure _I_ could sign up for classes and get an A&P if I wanted to and all I know about aircraft is what I've read here. What's preventing you from signing up for classwork and/or reading/learning on your own?

Comment: It's required to have 18 months of extensively record Powerplant experience in order to qualify to take the FAA Tests.  Since my primary AFSC is not in the field of Powerplant, it's near impossible for me to qualify even if crossed train. I would have to have not only 18 month OJT, But also accomplish this under an A&P licensed mechanic who would sign for me. I am trying to get the certificate, not enroll in a associates degree program.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, not familiar with the regulations there.

Answer (score 1):

Are there jobs for someone with just an airframe rating?

The answer to that is yes. While having both A & P ratings is a definite plus, there are places where a powerplant rating isn't necessary. There are many businesses that work with just avionics or interiors or structures, or departments segregated from powerplant. For jobs in these businesses (or departments) a powerplant rating is irrelevant.

And if you get to working at the component level, those shops (certificated repair stations) operate with Repairmen certificates. These are tied to being employed by the repair station and are generally obtained by completing specific in-house training [(ref. Part 65 Subpart E)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-65/subpart-E). I spent the majority of my non-AF career in avionics design and manufacture. The airframe certificate was only needed by the group doing installations. All the other technicians operated with a repairman certificate.

You could also seek out an business that allows you to work primarily in airframe and train in powerplant at the same time. Or just work in airframe and take classes part time to add the powerplant later.